# Started to teach myself Python and str if statements seem to not be working correctly

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input

Trying to create a simple transaction simulation just for practice using if statements, but when input is requested it defaults to the same if and doesn't change even when string literal variables are set in place.

I've tired moving things around, but everytime I run the code and it prompts me with Type "Deposit or "Withdraw" it will skip over proceed1 variable, and default to the amount1 variable input by prompting the user to "how much would you like to deposit."

```
import time
checking = 0
savings = 0
proceed1 = "Checking" or "checking"
proceed2 = "Savings" or "savings"
deposit = "Deposit" or "deposit"
withdraw = "Withdraw" or "withdraw"

time.sleep(1)
print("Thank you for choosing the Bank of Kegan")
time.sleep(1)
choice = str(input("Type \"Deposit\" or \"Withdraw\" \n "))
if choice == deposit:
    print("Deposit Transaction Initiated: Checking ")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Please choose an account you would like to Deposit into. ")
    account_choice = str(input("Type \"Checking\" or \"Savings\" \n "))
    if account_choice == proceed1:
        print("Checking Account Loading... \n")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Checking: $", checking, "\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        amount1 = int(input("Please type how much you'd like to deposit. \n "))
        time.sleep(.5)
        print("$", amount1, "Transaction Pending...")
        time.sleep(2)
        checking = (checking + amount1)
        print("Your new balance is: ")
        print("$", checking)
        exit()

    elif account_choice == proceed2:
        print("Savings Account Loading... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Savings: $", savings)
        time.sleep(2)
        amount2 = int(input("Please type how much you'd like to deposit. \n "))
        time.sleep(.5)
        print("$", amount2, "Transaction Pending... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        savings = (savings + amount2)
        print("Your new balance is: ")
        print("$", savings)
        exit()
    else:
     print("Please choose a valid argument ")
elif choice == withdraw:
    print("Withdraw Transaction Initiated: Checking ")
    print("Type what account you would like to withdraw from. ")
    choice2 = str(input("Checking or Savings"))
    if choice2 == proceed1:
        print("Withdraw Transaction Initiated: Checking ")
        print("Checking Account Loading... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Checking \n Balance: ", checking)
        withdraw1 = int(input("Type how much you would like to withdraw. "))
        print("$", withdraw1, "withdraw transaction pending... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        if checking == 0:
            print("You broke broke, make some money and come back later.")
        else:
         checking = withdraw1 - checking
         print("your new balance is: $", checking)
    elif choice2 == proceed2:
        time.sleep(.5)
        print("Savings Account Loading... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Savings \n Balance: ", savings)
        withdraw2 = int(input("Type how much you would like to withdraw. "))
        print("$", withdraw2, "withdraw transaction pending... ")
        time.sleep(2)
        if savings == 0:
            print("You broke broke, make some money and come back later.")
        else:
         savings = withdraw2 - savings
         print("your new balance is: $", savings)
    else:
        print("Please choose a valid argument.")
```

Comment: `proceed1 = "Checking" or "checking"`: this does not do what you think this is doing. You cannot store two different strings in a single variable like that.

Comment: This is not the correct way to define variables for what you want, it will always come off as the initial value...you should do it in a list `if selection in list` or you could just `.lower()` or `.upper()` the input for a single comparison